# Customized numeration in algorithmic

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I want to customize the numbering inside an algorithm. Here is a short MWE

```
\documentclass[article]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmicx,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require data ($X, y$); number of runs $K$; nominal level $q \in [0,1]$
\State Choose sequence $\{q_k\}_{k=1}^{K} \in [0,1]$ such that $q = \sum_{k=1}^{K} q_k$.
\For  {$k \in \{1,\dots,K\}$} 
    \State Apply knockoff/knockoff+ with nominal level $q_k$ and obtain selection set $\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_k}$.
\EndFor
\State Result: $K$ different selection sets $\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_1},\dots, \hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_K}$.
\State Aggregate the selection sets by taking their union
\begin{align}
\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q}^{U} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{K} \hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_k}.
\end{align} 
\Ensure Aggregated set $\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q}^{U}$ 
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

More specifically, I want to enumerate only the following lines marked in blue. To be more precise, I don't want the enumeration that results from \begin[algorithmic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRwHp.png), I just want to place a "1, 2 and 3" in front of the three lines there to make clear that these are 3 steps (and not 3 code lines).

[image]

Comment: Please see the updated answer with the added dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two new commands  --`\Staten` and `\Forn`-- have been defined to add an incremental  prefix (with a dot) to   `\State` and `\For`.

The counter used (`enumstate`) must be reset (if so desired) after each `algorithm`.

[image: d]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[article]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % loads algorithmicx

%% ******************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcounter{enumstate}
\stepcounter{enumstate}

\newcommand{\Staten}{\item[\theenumstate.]\stepcounter{enumstate}}% numbered state with dot
\algnewcommand\algorithmicforn{\hspace*{-3ex}\theenumstate.\stepcounter{enumstate} \ \textbf{for}} % numbered for with dot
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{Forn}{EndForn}[1]{ \algorithmicforn\  #1\ \algorithmicdo}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}%   
%% *******************************************

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \Require data ($X, y$); number of runs $K$; nominal level $q \in [0,1]$
    \Staten Choose sequence $\{q_k\}_{k=1}^{K} \in [0,1]$ such that $q = \sum_{k=1}^{K} q_k$.
    \Forn  {$k \in \{1,\dots,K\}$} 
        \State Apply knockoff/knockoff+ with nominal level $q_k$ and obtain selection set $\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_k}$.
    \EndForn
        \State Result: $K$ different selection sets $\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_1},\dots, \hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_K}$.
    \Staten  Aggregate the selection sets by taking their union
        \begin{align}
            \hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q}^{U} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{K} \hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_k}.
        \end{align} 
        \Ensure Aggregated set $\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q}^{U}$ 
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\setcounter{enumstate}{1} % resert counter <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Require data ($X, y$); number of runs $K$; nominal level $q \in [0,1]$
        \Staten Choose sequence $\{q_k\}_{k=1}^{K} \in [0,1]$ such that $q = \sum_{k=1}^{K} q_k$.
        \Forn  {$k \in \{1,\dots,K\}$} 
        \State Apply knockoff/knockoff+ with nominal level $q_k$ and obtain selection set $\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_k}$.
        \EndForn
        \State Result: $K$ different selection sets $\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_1},\dots, \hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_K}$.
        \Staten  Aggregate the selection sets by taking their union
        \begin{align}
            \hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q}^{U} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{K} \hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q_k}.
        \end{align} 
        \Ensure Aggregated set $\hat{\mathcal{S}}_{q}^{U}$ 
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that really helps a lot! One follow-up question, how can I adjust the numbering there to add a dot after each number, i..e  "1., 2., 3."

Comment: @Leo96 See the updated code with the dot.